# Teclado não reconhece Edittext

Tags: java, android

Tenho vários `EditText` dentro de um item da minha lista `ExpandleListView`.
Sempre ao clicar nos `EditText` aparece a mensagem abaixo e não é digitado texto no campo:

> getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
>   getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection

```
public View buscaView(int groupPosition){
        if(listaHolder.size() > 0){
            for(int i = 0; i < listaHolder.size(); i++){
                if(listaHolder.get(i).position == groupPosition){
                    return listaHolder.get(i).convertView;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

 @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(buscaView(groupPosition) == null) {
               LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
                        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_aneurisma, null);

                holder = new ItemSuporte();
                // Editexts
                holder.aneurismaLargura = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_largura);
                holder.aneurismaComprimento = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ed_comprimento);
                holder.ed_colo = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ed_colo);
                holder.ed_causa = (EditText)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.ed_causa);
                holder.ed_descricao = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ed_descricao);
                holder.ed_tratamento = (EditText)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.ed_tratamento);
                holder.ed_resultado_imediato = (EditText)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.ed_resultado_imediato);
                holder.ed_n_clips = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ed_n_clips);
                holder.ed_tempo_clipagem_temporaria = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ed_tempo_clipagem_temporaria);
                holder.ed_n_coils = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ed_n_coils);
                holder.ed_descricao_complicacoes_especificas = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ed_descricao_complicacoes_especificas);

                // Checkbos
                holder.cb_insucesso_terapeutico = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_insucesso_terapeutico);
                holder.cb_paralisia_incompleta = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_paralisia_incompleta);
                holder.cb_paralisia_completa = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_paralisia_completa);
                holder.cb_clipagem_temporaria = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_clipagem_temporaria);
                holder.cb_balao = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_balao);
                holder.cb_stent = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_stent);
                holder.cb_complicacoes_especificas_procedimento = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_complicacoes_especificas_procedimento);

                // View
                holder.conainner = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.container);

                //holder.convertView = convertView;
                holder.position = groupPosition;
                holder.convertView = convertView;
                //holder.convertView.setTag(holder);

                // Adicionando cada view  do ExpandleListView.
                listaHolder.add(holder);

                Log.e("Adapter", "Criou uma nova instância da View...");

        }
        else{
           Log.e("Adapter","Retornou uma instância existente..., Total de holders: " + listaHolder.size());
           holder = (ItemSuporte) buscaView(groupPosition).getTag();
        }

         return buscaView(groupPosition);
    }
```

Comment: Você poderia postar a parte do seu código onde faz a declaração e inicialização dos EditTexts? Acho que isso ajudaria a resolver este problema de forma mais rápida.

Comment: Coloquei o código

Comment: O problema é que meu Edittext perde o foco.

Answer (score -1):

ExpandleListView é muito bugado, acabei utilizando um ListView comum que ficou idêntico ao Expandle... 
Escondendo e mostrando o layout a cada clique para "expandir" o item da lista, assim como a manipulação da seta de Up e Down a cada "abertura" da lista. Ficou idêntico ao ExpandleListView só que sem bugs, recomendo para quem for utilizar essa abordagem.

Abraço.

Comment: mesmo que sua resposta esteja correta, é aconselhável adicionar ao mesmo um código para melhor entendimento, pois tem muita gente iniciando no mundo android e não faz a minima ideia do que voce está falando.